# Did MPs have to win a by-election before 1926 in order to join the government?

Tags: united-kingdom, history, cabinet, member-of-parliament

A [commentary in The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/opinion/2021/11/17/self-inflicted-mess-mps-second-jobs-causing-earthquake-westminster/) claimed that before 1926, MPs had to win a by-election to join the government. This got me rather perplexed.

> Mr Johnson has sensibly stopped short of joining Labour in pushing for an almost complete ban on second jobs, though it should be pointed out that being a government minister is also paid employment that keeps an MP away from his or her “main job”, whatever that is supposed to be. **Long ago, this used to be acknowledged since MPs were not paid at all and, until 1926, if they wanted to join the government they had to win a by-election.**
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

Why would MPs need to win a by-election to join the government? Am I understanding this paragraph wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This was called a [Ministerial by-election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministerial_by-election)

The principle was that by becoming a Minister, an MP was taking a new job and an office of profit from the Crown.  Since his paid job working as a paid adviser to the Monarch could cause a conflict of interest with he position representing his constituents, taking a ministerial role automatically removed the MP from Parliament.

To mitigate this, the possiblity of restanding as an Minister and MP and being re-elected was introduced (in 1707).  This allowed for MPs to be paid Ministers while retaining their seat in Parliament. It was a Whiggish policy to require the Monarch to appoint ministers from among Parliament.

This new system rapidly changed the nature of Parliament and of government, with the new Minister-MPs forming a cabinet, with a chairman (who was parodied as a "Prime" Minister) holding almost complete executive power.

These by elections rapidly became a rubber stamping process, often uncontested and with very low turnouts.